# How to make QTMovie play file from URL with forced (MP3) type?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mp3, qtkit, progressive-download

I'm using QTKit to progressively download and play an MP3 from a URL. According to [this documentation](http://www.meandmark.com/qtkitaudiopart2.html), this is the code I should use to accomplish that:

```
NSURL *mp3URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://foo.com/bar.mp3"];

NSError *error = nil;
QTMovie *sound = [[QTMovie alloc] initWithURL:mp3URL error:&error];
[sound play];
```

This works, and does exactly what I want — the MP3 URL is lazily downloaded and starts playing immediately. However, if the URL does not have the ".mp3" path extension, it fails:

```
NSURL *mp3URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://foo.com/bar"];

NSError *error = nil;
QTMovie *sound = [[QTMovie alloc] initWithURL:mp3URL error:&error];
[sound play];
```

No error is given, no exception is raised; the duration of the sound is just set to zero, and nothing plays.

The only way I have found to work around this is to force a type by loading the data manually and using a QTDataReference:

```
NSURL *mp3URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://foo.com/bar"];
NSData *mp3Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:mp3URL];

QTDataReference *dataReference = 
    [QTDataReference dataReferenceWithReferenceToData:mp3Data
                                                 name:@"bar.mp3"
                                             MIMEType:nil];
NSError *error = nil;
QTMovie *sound = [[QTMovie alloc] initWithDataReference:dataReference error:&error];
[sound play];
```

However, this forces me to completely download ALL of the MP3 synchronously before I can start playing it, which is obviously undesirable. Is there any way around this?

Thanks.

### Edit

Actually, it seems that the path extension has nothing to do with it; the Content-Type is simply not being set in the HTTP header. Even so, the latter code works and the former does not. Anyone know of a way to fix this, without having access to the server?

### Edit 2

Anyone? I can't find information about this *anywhere*, and Google frustratingly now shows this page as the top result for most of my queries...

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas. (The first one being a bit hacky):
To work around the missing content type, you could embed a small Cocoa webserver that supplements the missing header field and route your NSURL over that "proxy".

Some Cocoa http server implementations:

- http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/
- http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html
- http://culturedcode.com/cocoa/

The second one would be, to switch to a lower level framework (From QTKit to AudioToolbox).
You'd need more code, but there are some very good resources out there on how to stream mp3 using AudioToolbox.
e.g.:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html

Personally I'd go with the second option. AudioToolbox isn't as straightforward as QTKit but it offers a clean solution to your problem. It's also available on both - iOS and Mac OS - so you will find plenty of information.

**Update:**
Did you try to use another initializer? e.g.

```
+ (id)movieWithAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes error:(NSError **)errorPtr
```

You can insert your URL for the key `QTMovieURLAttribute` and maybe you can compensate the missing content type by providing other attributes in that dictionary.
This open source project has a QTMovie category that contains methods to accomplish similar things:
http://vidnik.googlecode.com/svn-history/r63/trunk/Source/Categories/QTMovie+Async.m

Comment: AudioStreamer looks promising, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for my use case as I frequently receive an "Unable to configure network read stream." after pausing and then playing in the middle of an MP3. (Hence why I'm looking for a *progressive downloader* instead of a streamer.)

Comment: Also, “AudioToolbox isn't as straightforward as QTKit", is a bit of an understatement, isn't it? Core Audio is often cited as the [hardest API on OS X](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/why-coreaudio-is-hard.html), and I'm certain is one of the easiest to subtly misuse. Since what I'm doing is relatively simplistic, I'd much prefer to leave the heavy lifting up to a higher-level API that "does it right".

Comment: Yes, Core Audio is hard and I can totally understand that you look into high level APIs first. I updated my original answer with another idea. (Didn't test it though. Can you post some of the problematic URLs?)

Comment: Thanks for the help and further suggestion; unfortunately I get the same result, though. Here's an example of a "bad" URL: http://meeselet.s3.amazonaws.com/example

Answer (score 0):

If you thought [weichsel's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394968/how-to-make-qtmovie-play-file-from-url-with-forced-mp3-type/4421683#4421683) first solution was hacky, you're going to *love* this one:

The culprit is the `Content-Type` header, as you have determined. Had `QTKit.framework` used Objective-C internally, this would be a trivial matter of overriding `-[NSHTTPURLResponse allHeaderFields]` with a category of your choosing. However, `QTKit.framework` (for better or worse) uses Core Foundation (and Core Services) internally. These are both C-based frameworks and there is no elegant way of overriding functions in C.

That said, there *is* a method, just not a pretty one. Function interposition is even [documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/UsingDynamicLibraries.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002182-SW14) by Apple, but seems to be a bit behind the times, compared to the remainder of their documentation.

In essence, you want something along the following lines:

```
typedef struct interpose_s {
    void *new_func;
    void *orig_func;
} interpose_t;

CFStringRef myCFHTTPMessageCopyHeaderFieldValue (
                                                 CFHTTPMessageRef message,
                                                 CFStringRef headerField
                                                 );

static const interpose_t interposers[] __attribute__ ((section("__DATA, __interpose"))) = {
    { (void *)myCFHTTPMessageCopyHeaderFieldValue, (void *)CFHTTPMessageCopyHeaderFieldValue }
};

CFStringRef myCFHTTPMessageCopyHeaderFieldValue (
                                                 CFHTTPMessageRef message,
                                                 CFStringRef headerField
                                                 ) {
    if (CFStringCompare(headerField, CFSTR("Content-Type"), 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        return CFSTR("audio/x-mpeg");
    } else {
        return CFHTTPMessageCopyHeaderFieldValue(message, headerField);
    }
}
```

You might want to add logic specific to your application in terms of handling the `Content-Type` field lest your application break in weird and wonderful ways when every HTTP request is determined to be an audio file.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `http://` with `icy://`.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an instance like this...

```
QTMovie *aPlayer  = [QTMovie movieWithAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                 fileUrl, QTMovieURLAttribute,
                                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], QTMovieOpenForPlaybackAttribute,
                                                 /*[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], QTMovieOpenAsyncOKAttribute,*/
                                                 nil] error:error];
```